# How can I convert timestamps to dates in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

How can I convert timestamps to dates in SQLite?

The following code only produces a Timestamp column and a Date columns with NULL values. The the SQL code needs to convert from a "08/28/2020 8:00" format.

**SQL CODE:**

'''Select Timestamp, strftime('%m-%d-%Y', Timestamp) as Date
FROM Room_Data'''

The SQLite documentation is pretty clear, but I can't seem to get the desired result.

Comment: Please show some of your data and expected results.

Comment: Current = "08/28/2020 8:00", Needed = "08/28/2020"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strftime is meant to format a date, rather than perform conversion.

In the meantime you could try something like that to gather the pieces:

```
SELECT Timestamp, 
SUBSTR(c,7,4) || '-' || SUBSTR(Timestamp,1,2) || '-' || SUBSTR(Timestamp,4,2) as Date
FROM Room_Data
```

Since SQlite doesn't really have the concept of a date, unlike other DBMS, the best choice would be to convert your dates to integer, either as Unix timestamps or in string form (YYYY-MM-DD) but storing dates as integer like 20201010 would be acceptable too.

NB: be careful with names like Timestamp or Date, they are **reserved keywords** in many programming languages and DBMSes.

Answer (score 0):

The original code won't work in Windows 10 for some reason. Trying this from a Linux distro (Kubuntu, in this case) seems to resolve the issue. In Windows, the date needs to be converted to a '2020-01-01' format to actually work.

SQLite is amazing, but not sure why functionality changes for Windows 10. Feel free to comment if you know more about the differences.